# unhandled exception(DWrite.dll) Access violation reading location in a WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, unmanaged

I'm developing a `WPF` app, with an embedded `Winform WebBrowser Control`, as it sometimes needs to show local html files to the user. Of course, I'm not sure the embedded `WebBrowser` control is the culprit of this exception because this exception maybe thrown when the `WebBrowser` control is not showing. Actually, I could encounter the crash caused by this exception **only when changing system's resolution**. And I have tried to do nothing during system display setting change but I did not get any lucky.

I received following exception information when trying to debug the dump file below:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC7A329CDA (DWrite.dll) in
>   MyApp.exe_150811_174322.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

### Dump Summary

> Dump File:    MyApp.exe_150811_174322.dmp :
>   D:\Software\Procdump\MyApp_150811_174322.dmp Last Write
>   Time: 2015/8/11 17:43:26 Process Name:    MyApp.exe :
>   D:\Work\Project\MyApp.exe Process Architecture:   x64 Exception
>   Code: 0xC0000005 Exception Information:   The thread tried to read from
>   or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the
>   appropriate access. Heap Information: Present

### System Information

> OS Version:   6.3.9600 CLR Version(s):    4.0.30319.34209

Obviously, it's an un-managed exception so that neither `DispatcherUnhandledException` event nor `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event could be leveraged to handle this exception. In other words, my app will crash which definitely is a disaster when encountering this exception. Is there any way to handle un-managed exception in `WPF`?

I googled "`DWrite.dll`". It's a `DLL` for `Microsoft DirectX Typography Services`. I haven't seen any link between my app and "`DWrite.dll`". Any suggestion here is welcome.

Comment: "as it sometimes needs to show local html files". The WPF WebBrowser control is also able to do that.

Comment: Browsers crash, it is a fact of life.  Normal browsers protect themselves by rendering html and executing javascript in a separate process.  No such protection when you use WebBrowser.  DWrite.dll is the DirectWrite api implementation, used both by WPF and by browsers.  It gets hammered billions of times every day.  You're pretty low on the rendering chain when this bombs, there's isn't much beneath.  Except for the kind of software that's responsible for 95% of crashes like this, the video driver.

Comment: Thanks Clemens and Hans Passant.

Comment: Thanks Clemens and Hans Passant. I believe I have found the culprit of the crash which is the ViewBox control. More specifically, the usage of the ViewBox control. I put an ViewBox control in my main window as the root element in order to adapt different resolutions. It's an awful idea and I have decided to refactor the UI by using flow layout.